# How to notice edges in each other?

Tags: modeling, game-engine

When I notice 2 edges in each other, I select both of the points and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, which allows me to merge them. I always merge them at center to have both points merge and have them as one point. I always, when I finish a model, select every edge in wireframe mode twice to see if there are edges in each other that I may have modeled by mistake. Is there any way the system could help me with this task? It takes a lot of time and I could always miss something. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: did you try Remove doubles ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use <kbd>W</kbd>>*Remove Doubles*, with everything selected <kbd>A</kbd>, this will find all the vertices within `n` units of another vertex and merge them. `n` is defined by the merge distance, which you can modify using <kbd>F6</kbd> after executing the command.

[image]

Comment: I never knew this feature existed, thanks!